# Derive the continuity equation

Tags: continuity, fluid-dynamics

How do I use this equation $$ \frac {D}{Dt} (\rho J) = 0$$

to derive the continuity equation

$$ \frac {D}{Dt} \rho \nabla \cdot v = 0$$

Comment: Could you state what $J$ is?

Comment: J is the determinant of the deformation gradient tensor. $ dx = J dX $

Comment: Sorry. What I meant was could you write out the formula for $J$ explicitly.

Comment: There isn't any formula. The book states that J is the determinant of a deformation gradient. $
   J = \det{\boldsymbol{F}}
  $